# How to connect a watch with the iPhone

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

I understand that the watch app is an extention of the iOS app. To install an app, we must install it in iPhone and that will install on the paired iWatch. How does the iPhone identifies it's watch where the iwatch app will be installed or how we can pair these two devices?

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's [WatchKit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/index.html):

> A Watch app is required for all interactions on Apple Watch. Because a
>   Watch app extends the behavior of your existing iOS app, the Watch app
>   and WatchKit extension are bundled together and packaged inside your
>   iOS app bundle. During installation of your iOS app, the system
>   prompts the user to install the Watch app if a paired Apple Watch is
>   present.

Answer (score 0):

> How does the iPhone identifies it's watch app or how we can pair these two devices?

You do not have to do anything programatically. When user interacts with the Watch App, it will identify the appropriate WatchKitExtension and send messages to it.

From the [pre release docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/DesigningaWatchKitApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH3-SW1) :

*When the user interacts with your Watch app, Apple Watch looks for an appropriate storyboard scene to display. It selects the scene based on whether the user is viewing your app’s glance, is viewing a notification, or is interacting with your app’s main interface. After choosing a scene, Watch OS tells the paired iPhone to launch your WatchKit extension and load the appropriate objects for running that interface. **All of this communication happens transparently behind the scenes***

Comment: Thats great! "Watch OS tells the paired iPhone to launch your WatchKit extension ". How does this pairing happen :)

Comment: @KannanRajendran Thats not disclosed.

Comment: You don't need to know how the pairing happens it will just be there.

Answer (score 0):

From discussion on apple forum and response from Apple people.

Only one watch may be paired with one phone.

If there is no connection from watch to phone (no power) then app on watch wont start.